# Safari app extension Popover and Command at the same time

Tags: swift, xcode, safari, safari-extension, sfsafariviewcontroller

I have a safari app extension, which open a popover by clicking on the toolbar item.

```
<key>SFSafariToolbarItem</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Action</key>
        <string>Popover</string>
        <key>Identifier</key>
        <string>Button</string>
        <key>Image</key>
        <string>ToolbarItemIcon.pdf</string>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>My Extension</string>
    </dict>
```

This is the current settings in my `info.plist` file, in my case I want to show popover on toolbar item click only if user meet some requirements. If the user not meet the requirements and click the toolbar item, I want to send a message to inected script to trigger some action without opening popover.

I am new to safari app extension development, not able to figure out the way.

Comment: It appears that popovers and commands are mutually exclusive ‍♂️ I’ve tried setting action to `Command`, then `toolbarItemClicked` starts getting called, but getting the item and calling `showPopover()` does nothing. Oh God it’s such a trainwreck API.